# Getting a '403 Forbidden' error on deploying a Laravel application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Laravel application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. However, on navigating to the URL of the application I see a `403 Forbidden` error.

The last two lines of my `/var/log/nginx/error.log` are as follows.

```
2022/11/21 08:23:20 [error] 3614#3614: *31864 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.31.39.157, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "172.31.47.15"
2022/11/21 08:23:31 [error] 3614#3614: *31865 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.31.11.188, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "172.31.47.15"
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Check did nginx start by user root.
- Check the nginx.conf. Is there any configuration like the following:

```
allow 192.168.1.1;
deny all;
```

The config means only 192.168.1.1 can access.